# Hard Drive Power On Hours

Tags: hard-drive, sas

I am looking to purchase used drives for example these models MB2000FBZPN or MB2000FCZGH or MB2000FCWDF

I only see 3 year warranty listed

Seller says this has been used for 3.5 Years so that comes out to be 1,277.5 hours

What is the best way to find how many hours can this would last more ?

Not looking for opinion but any factual information for specific types or models of drives, if the vendor publishes how many hours this has lasted in tests etc

Opinion based answers will not be helpful

http://www.extremetech.com/computing/170748-how-long-do-hard-drives-actually-live-for

Comment: "How long is a piece of string?" Drives work until they fail, not a moment longer, not a moment less.

Comment: :) can't find for these ones but i have find total power on hours listed other drives or i am dreaming :)

Comment: Total hours is but one figure from many that may contribute to a drive's demise - but it really is not anything to rely on. A drive will last until it fails. I have drives here that have been running reliably 24/7 for 8 years or more, & others that failed within one. Re your edit - Backblaze results are a great source of data… but they still do not predict the fail of any given drive at any given time. There is no answer to your question.

Comment: Can you please share models of the drives that you have running for 8 years? i need to buy 2TB drives in bulk and have limited budget

Comment: Buy new ones, don't buy used. HD prices are rock-bottom these days. My survivors are mainly Hitachi & Toshiba… but so were my early fails.

Comment: Thank you, Any idea where i can find Total Hours of these drives or is total hours is how many hours this drives has been powered on, Does HDD vendors publish any hours they have tested these drives for

Comment: agreed on the new and used factor, so this drive used is $60 on ebay and similar compatible new one is for $75 on amazon. so unless i can get these used for $25 each i will not go with used

Comment: Total hours of use is rated as MTBF, but even Seagate will tell you this is not actual real-life use number... Many factors relate to hard drive reliability. This may give you some insight: http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/174791en?language=en_US

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the lifetime of a typical hard disk?](http://superuser.com/questions/37049/what-is-the-lifetime-of-a-typical-hard-disk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question is "we can not provide you for the answer you are looking for as it doesnt exist".    You are trying to purchase drives which are past there prime, and which are being sold because they are aging.

You are also asking a question which involves a lot of variables.   This means that anyones answer will be an opinion only, albeit it may be a very informed one.

Information can be drawn from 3 major sources -

1. BackupBlaze [information for drives of this era](https://www.backblaze.com/blog/what-hard-drive-should-i-buy/).  Unfortunately, but entirely unsurprisingly as you are looking at HP rebranded SAS disks I could not find any of these drives in the studies, and their usage case is most likely very different to yours.
2. [Google Disk Failure analysis](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//archive/disk_failures.pdf).  This is probably to old to provide data on your specific drives, but does show statistical probabilities about failures and causes on hard drives.
3. Manufacturer data sheets - because these are HP and very specific you
   would need to go to HP about them.  In fact, I think you will find that HP do not provide any "single model" drive information - rather they provide a warranty with their drives and take whatever they can get cost effectively, internally test it and rebrand it.

If you are trying to do a large drive deployment on the cheap, rather then buy secon hand HP branded drives, you should consider purchasing drives from Hitachi (or Western Digital or Seagate - in that very rough order for reliability based on BackupBlaze stats), and stick them in cheap Chinese caddies (which have no electronics in them anyway, so its not high risk).  You will also be able to get decent MTBF specs from these companies and more commonly tested drives.

Comment: Thank you makes sense it's always better to double check to make sure I am not missing anything your answer perfectly fits the question