# Can I either find the fault data of a specific HDD model or predict it?

Tags: hard-drive

**Background:**

In many occasions, I suffered a lot from HDD failure. I found that even reputable brands could faulty model. For example, all of my 1.5TB WD Green HDDs died within the 1st year.

I personally do not care about company’s warranty replacement policy since I don’t want to spend time and replace the HDD – too often.

I personally don’t care about the speed of the HDD. I do care about the **longevity and reliability of an HDD.** The problem is most benchmark sites compare HDD performance rather than their reliability.

**Question:**

Is there any benchmark resource that assesses the longevity and reliability of an HDD model?

What is the best way to assess or predict the reliability of a new arrival HDD model? For example, I rather not to gamble and install something like [this](http://amzn.com/B00FQH7MQ2) HDD then have to spend time and replace it in two years.

Comment: You can't.  There are literally only 2-3 major manfactures of mechanical HDDs and there really is no difference between them, the one brand that fails less often, is owned by Western Digitial.  Your best best is to assume your mechnical drive will fail, purchase a drive with a 3-5 year warranty, and use that warranty when the drive fails.  I won't name the brand, by name, for obvious reasons.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the lifetime of a typical hard disk?](http://superuser.com/questions/37049/what-is-the-lifetime-of-a-typical-hard-disk)

Comment: It is worth pointing out that a SSHD is as likely to fail as a traditional HDD.  Its still a mechanical hdd, the mechanical compondents, will still fail its just a matter of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a new project to estimate reliability of hard drives according to Google/Backblaze studies: https://github.com/linuxhw/SMART/blob/master/README.md

It measures reliability by counting several SMART errors, that usually correlate with real hard drive failures: Reported_Uncorrect, Reallocated_Sector_Ct, Current_Pending_Sector, etc.